# Retrieving object and predicate for a subject without sparql

Tags: rdf, jena, triples

I retrieved the subject through the model using `getSubject()` and for this subject I want to create a relation for their respective object and predicate. How to retrieve an object and predicate for a particular subject through jena and without sparql?

Comment: See the javadoc for `Resource`.

Comment: if we take resource then we can get individually but i want to know the predicate and object of particular subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the predicates and objects of a particular subject given model m:

```
// The resource you already had:
Resource subject; // = m.getResource(NAMESPACE + "subject");

// This creates a 'list' (iterator) over all the satements containing your subject
StmtIterator stmtIterator = m.listStatements(subject, null, (RDFNode) null);

// While you have not processed all these statements:
while (stmtIterator.hasNext()){

     // Grab the next statement
     Statement s = stmtIterator.next();

     // Retrieve the predicate(property) and the object from the statement
     Property predicate = s.getPredicate();
     Resource object = s.getObject();

     // Do something with your predicate
     // Do something with your object
}
```

**However if you mean you want to grab a predicate and a subject from the model to add it to the subject you retrieved:**

```
Property property = m.getProperty(NAMESPACE + "propertyName");
Resource object = m.getResource(NAMESPACE + "objectName");
subject.addProperty(property, object);
```